# How to show the Google Photo Sphere on an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm developing Google Street View app for iOS.
I think Photo Sphere is not sopported iOS API, but it's sopported Android API.
How do i show the Photo Sphere? I can't think of any good ideas.
Use cordova-plugin-googlemaps for PhoneGap?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use OpenGL ES and map the image as a spheremap texture. or have a sphere mesh and use a standard texture coordinates.
2. You can also achieve the same effect using UIView customisation.